# Printf.fprintf format: adding spaces to the right of a text

Tags: printing, ocaml

I have a normal function `print`:

```
(* abc.ml *)
let print (chan: out_channel) (x: t) : unit =
  Printf.fprintf chan "%s" (to_string x)
```

Then I call this function by several occasions, for instance:

```
Printf.fprintf stdout "Here it is: %a\n" Abc.print x
```

I know `"%15s"` as parameter of `print` permits to adding spaces in front of a text so that the whole length is `15`. However, I don't want to control the length in `Abs.print`, I want to control it when I call it via `%a`. But `Printf.fprintf stdout "Here it is: %15a\n" Abc.print x` doesn't seem to work. Also I want to add the spaces to the right of the text, instead of the left.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer is to use `*` as your field width and to supply a negative integer.

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.00.1

# Printf.printf "[%*s]\n" (-15) "string";;
[string         ]
- : unit = ()
```

**Update**

In your more complicated scenario, you should be able to do something like this:

```
# let to_string s = s;;
val to_string : 'a -> 'a = <fun>

# let print width chan x = Printf.fprintf chan "%*s" width (to_string x);;
val print : int -> out_channel -> string -> unit = <fun>

# Printf.fprintf stdout "Here it is: [%a]\n" (print (-15)) "string";;
Here it is: [string         ]
- : unit = ()
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I want to use `%a`, instead of `%s`, it seems that `Printf.fprintf stdout "[%*a]\n" (-15) Abs.print x` doesn't work...

Comment: Try `Printf.fprintf stdout "[%a]" (Abs.print (-15)) x` perhaps. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the `print` of all my modules have the same signature `: out_channel -> t -> unit`, I really don't want to change it... Let's see if there will be other comments...

Comment: It looks to me like you want some "plumbing" that's not available. The `%a` format leaves all printing up to your print function and passes only the value to be printed. There's no place to pass the width.